# How to sum specific integer values of Python List

Tags: python

I'm trying to sum integer values from the list using sum function. Unfortunately, it is adding all the values of the list but not those which I need from the user.

**Here is my code:**

```
tourist_attractions = []
distance = []
entry_cost = []

for i in range(3):
    tourist_attractions.append (input("Enter Tourist place: "))


    tourist_distance =(int(input("Enter distance: ")))

    if tourist_distance > 50:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        continue

    if tourist_distance <= 50:
        distance.append(tourist_distance)

    cost = (float(input("Enter cost: ")))

    if cost > 100:
        print("cost must be between 1-100")
        continue

    if cost > 0 or cost <= 100:
        entry_cost.append(cost)

print()

for line in tourist_attractions:
    print("Place:", line)

for line in distance:
    print("Distance:", line)

for line in entry_cost:
    print("Cost:", line)


print()

number_of_places_to_visit = int(input("Total number of places to visit: "))

x = 1

while x <= number_of_places_to_visit:

    select_tourist_place = input("select tourist place, 0-3: ")

    x = x + 1


    if select_tourist_place == "0":
        print(tourist_attractions[0], distance[0], entry_cost[0])

    elif select_tourist_place == "1":
        print(tourist_attractions[1], distance[1], entry_cost[1])

    elif select_tourist_place == "2":
        print(tourist_attractions[2], distance[2], entry_cost[2])

    elif select_tourist_place == "3":
        print(tourist_attractions[3], distance[3], entry_cost[3])

    elif select_tourist_place == "4":
        print(tourist_attractions[4], distance[4], entry_cost[4])



print("total cost: " , sum(entry_cost))
```

**Result I am getting:**

```
Enter Tourist place: London
Enter distance: 25
Enter cost: 15
Enter Tourist place: Manchester
Enter distance: 30
Enter cost: 15
Enter Tourist place: Scotland
Enter distance: 50
Enter cost: 20

Place: London
Place: Manchester
Place: Scotland
Distance: 25
Distance: 30
Distance: 50
Cost: 15.0
Cost: 15.0
Cost: 20.0

Total number of places to visit: 2
select tourist place, 0-3: 0
London 25 15.0
select tourist place, 0-5: 1
Manchester 30 15.0
total cost:  50.0
>>>
```

I can understand, at the moment it is summing up all the appended list of entry_cost and giving me the total of 50 which should be 15 from London and 15 from Manchester. Any help?

Comment: Yes, it is basically adding all the list. I need only those additions which user is selecting so in this case it should be 0 for London 15 and 1 for Manchester which should be 15 and total will be then 30.

Comment: something is wrong with your output it states "select tourist place, 0-5: 1" however the string you print is "select tourist place, 0-3: "

Comment: For testing purpose I reduce the loop to 3 not 5. I think it won't be an issue.

Comment: It's adding all elements of the `entry_cost` list because you tell it to do so, here: `print("total cost: " , sum(entry_cost))`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("total cost: " , sum(entry_cost))
```

definitely states your are iterating over ALL entry costs. You would want to store the selected indices and sum over the entries of those indices.